# Running VS Code as sudo in terminal gives loop error

Tags: sudo, visual-studio-code

When I try to run VS Code from terminal with this command:

```
sudo code --user-data-dir=~/.vscode-root --no-sandbox
```

I am getting gray window, and this error which goes to infinity until I stop the process. What's seems to be wrong here - I am on Mint 21.1:

```
[25709:0612/090822.505625:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(521)] Network service crashed, restarting service.
[0612/090822.521896:FATAL:electron_main_delegate.cc(304)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
[25709:0612/090822.671724:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(521)] Network service crashed, restarting service.
```

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me - using xfce4 -, it seems an update could be the problem, version 1.79.0 produced this symptom, when reverted to 1.74.3 started up with no problem (removed data folder and extensions while trying to make it work so don't know if the old settings can be saved).